# How to resize root partition size to use whole disk size after deploying by ironic?

Tags: deployment, openstack

I set up standalone ironic with mitaka version. I created a whole disk image (ubuntu14.04) by virt-install and used Coreos pxe image ([Here](http://tarballs.openstack.org/ironic-python-agent/coreos/files)) as deploy kernel and ramdisk. (ubuntu 14.04) The disk image size is 10G, and it could be deployed successfully on my node. When I logged in the node and checked the disk info, it only used 10G disk size for /dev/sda. The physical disk size of node is 500G.

How do I make my image to use whole disk size of node after deploying? Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a swap partition after the root partition and that will block the online growing of the root FS.

You need to either move the swap to the front of the disk or remove it entirely.